# Lucene IndexWriter OutOfMemory exception

Tags: java, lucene

I have two big files ( ~ 200 MB) in one directory and would like to build index on them, so here is my code:

```
public class LuceneUtil {
      private void indexDoc(IndexWriter indexWriter, Path file, long lastModified) throws IOException{
        try (InputStream stream = Files.newInputStream(file)) {
            Document document = new Document();

            Field pathField = new StringField("path", file.toString(), Field.Store.YES);
            document.add(pathField);
            document.add(new LongField("modified", lastModified, Field.Store.NO));
            document.add(new TextField("contents", new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(stream, StandardCharsets.UTF_8))));

            if (indexWriter.getConfig().getOpenMode() == IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND) {
                // new index
                indexWriter.addDocument(document);
            } else {
                // update existing index
                indexWriter.updateDocument(new Term("path", file.toString()), document);
            }
        }
    }

    private void indexDocs(final IndexWriter indexWriter, Path path) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, IOException {
        if (Files.isDirectory(path)) {
            ForkJoinPool FJ_POOL = new ForkJoinPool(3);
            List<Path> files = FSUtils.findAllFiles(path.toString());

            FJ_POOL.submit(() -> files.parallelStream().forEach(t -> {
                try {

                    indexDoc(indexWriter, t, FSUtils.getFileBasicAttribute(t).lastModifiedTime().toMillis());
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    logger.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                }
            })).get();
            FJ_POOL.shutdown();
//            Files.walkFileTree(path, new SimpleFileVisitor<Path>() {
//               @Override
//               public FileVisitResult visitFile (Path file, BasicFileAttributes attrs) throws IOException {
//                   try {
//
//                    indexDoc(indexWriter, file, attrs.lastModifiedTime().toMillis());
//                   } catch (IOException ex) {
//                       ex.printStackTrace();
//                   }
//                   return FileVisitResult.CONTINUE;
//               }
//            });
        } else {
            indexDoc(indexWriter, path, Files.getLastModifiedTime(path).toMillis());
        }
    }

    public void buildIndex(String pathToDocsDir, String pathToIndexDir) throws ExecutionException, InterruptedException, IOException{
        Path docPath = Paths.get(pathToDocsDir);
        Path indexPath = Paths.get(pathToIndexDir);
        long start = System.currentTimeMillis();

        try(Directory dir = FSDirectory.open(indexPath.toFile());
            Analyzer analyzer = new StandardAnalyzer()) {

            IndexWriterConfig iwc = new IndexWriterConfig(Version.LATEST, analyzer);
            iwc.setOpenMode(IndexWriterConfig.OpenMode.CREATE_OR_APPEND);
            try (IndexWriter indexWriter = new IndexWriter(dir, iwc)) {
                indexDocs(indexWriter, docPath);
            }
        }
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) throws ExecutionException,   InterruptedException, IOException{
      LuceneUtils luceneUtils = new LuceneUtils();

      String docPath = "/home/TestFolder";
      String indexPath = "/home/IndexFolder";
      try {
          luceneUtils.buildIndex(docPath, indexPath);
      } catch (IOException ex) {
          ex.printStackTrace();
      }
   }

}
```

So from my code you can see that I use one `IndexWriter` object for both files and try to build index files in parallel. After few minutes when my program was started I get next exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException:
>   java.lang.OutOfMemoryError    at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1006)     at
>   com.service.utils.LuceneUtils.indexDocs(LuceneUtils.java:70)  at
>   com.service.utils.LuceneUtils.buildIndex(LuceneUtils.java:100)    at
>   com.service.utils.LuceneUtils.main(LuceneUtils.java:138)  at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)   at
>   sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:497)     at
>   com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:140)
>   Caused by: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>     at
>   sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>     at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422)
>     at
>   java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.getThrowableException(ForkJoinTask.java:598)
>     at java.util.concurrent.ForkJoinTask.get(ForkJoinTask.java:1005)

Does it possible to use one `IndexWriter` in parallel mode? How could I fix my question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lucene has a nice function to parallelize indexing process. If you has indexed your files in RAMDirectory or FSDirectory you can merge them into one index.
You must use [addIndexes](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#addIndexes(org.apache.lucene.store.Directory...)) for preparing and use [forceMerge](https://lucene.apache.org/core/4_7_0/core/org/apache/lucene/index/IndexWriter.html#forceMerge(int)) to complete merging. 
Thus you can split your files into separate sections, index them in parallel and finally merge them.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, do you mean use separate index writer for big files?

Comment: You can divide-logically- your files into **n** groups. Then index each group in separate index then merge indexes into one. Indexing those separate groups can be done in parallel and the cost of merging is not much.

Answer (score 0):

You can assign more memory to the JVM using the `-Xmx` flag when you launch your program. For example the flag `-Xmx4G` will assign 4 GB of RAM to the JVM. This will most likely solve your error if you have enough extra memory left.

If you're using Eclipse you can set the flags from `Run -> Run configurations -> Arguments`, by passing `-Xmx` to the `VM arguments` textbox.

Comment: Thanks for reply, yes it's working but we don't have ability to increase memory on server.